# why spark reads and writes so fast from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I understand the advantage of spark in terms of processing large scale data in parallel and in-mem.

But how does it not hit a bottleneck in terms of read/write to S3 when reading/writing data from/to S3.  Is that handled in some efficient form by the S3 storage service?  Is S3 distributed storage?  Please provide some explanation and if possible links on how to learn more about this.

Comment: Funny, I always ask myself why they are so slow :)

Comment: lol.  I meant in comparison to a non distributed storage system where the I/O rate of the hard drive is a huge bottleneck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only bottlenecks within AWS are:

- A [network bandwidth limitation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/) on Amazon EC2 instances, based upon the Instance Type (Basically, larger instances have more network bandwidth)
- The speed of [Amazon EBS storage volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) (Provisioned IOPS supports up to 20,000 IOPS)

Throughput within a Region, such as between Amazon EC2 and Amazon S3, is extremely high and is unlikely to limit your ability to transfer data (aside from the EC2 network bandwidth limitation mentioned above).

Amazon S3 is distributed over many servers across multiple Availability Zones within a Region. At very high speeds, Amazon S3 does have some recommended [Request Rate and Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html), but this is only when making more than 300 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per second or more than 800 GET requests per second for a particular bucket.

Apache Spark is typically deployed across **multiple nodes**. Each node has  network bandwidth available based on its Instance Type. The **parallel nature** of Spark means that it can transfer data to/from Amazon S3 much faster than could be done by a single instance.

Comment: @jrotenstein thanks!  to be more specific, let us say I save X TB/PB of textbooks data in S3, and I execute the typical word count map reduce example in a spark cluster.  Let us also assume half of the data can fit in ram (by ram defined as the sum of ram of all spark workers).  What'd be the percentage of time getting the data into mem versus the time doing the map and reduce steps versus the time of writing the (word, count) tuples back to disk.  As of the CPU speed of each worker I'd assume a standard EC2 instance (i.e., r3.2xlarge or sthg like that).

Comment: You'll have to run a spark job and look at the statistics to figure that out. The first run through data will always be the slowest, when it is loaded into Spark and (presumably) cached. Subsequent access to that data will be much faster. Thus, Spark is better for situations where you are processing the same data multiple times (eg Machine Learning). If you're just accessing the data once, you won't see much benefit compared to non-memory resident query engines.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Spark talks to S3 via the client library from Amazon on EMR, or from the Apache Hadoop team elsewhere. If you use s3a:// URLs, you are using the most recent ASF client.

We've been doing a lot of work there on speeding things up, see [HADOOP-11694](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11694).

The performance killers have turned out to be

1. Excessive numbers of HEAD requests when working out files exist (too
   many checks in the code). Fix: cut down on these
2. Closing and reopening connections on seeks. Fix: (a) lazy seek (only
   do the seek on the read(), not the seek() call), (b) forward seek by
   reading and discarding data. Efficient even up to a few hundred KB
   (YMMV, etc)
3. For binary ORC/Parquet files, adding a special fadvise=random mode,
   which doesn't attempt a full GET of the source file, instead reads
   in blocks. If we need to seek back or a long-way forward, the rest
   of the block discarded and the HTTP 1.1 connection reused: no need
   to abort the connection and renegotiate a new one.

Some detail is in this talk from last month: [Spark and Object Stores](https://youtu.be/ND4L_zSDqF0), though it doesn't go into the new stuff (in Hadoop 2.8 (forthcoming), HDP 2.5 (shipping), maybe in CDH some time) in depth. It will recommend various settings for performance though, which are valid today.

Also do make sure any compression you use is splittable (LZO, snappy, ...), and that your files not so small that there's too much overhead in listing the directory and opening them.